# unable to access my bitbucket account after configuring ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to connect my laptop with my but bucket account. I went through the documentation and did as it was mentioned in this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

something like this:

[image: SSH keygen]

After that I configured my bit bucket setting and added the key:

[image: SSH config bitbucket]

But whenever I try to clone my repository you can see in the first image I get th error of

> ssh: Connect to host bitbucket.org port:22 connection time out

Same thing happens if I check my user name with command:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

[image: git bitbucket]

Help me out with these.

Comment: Does your network allow outgoing port:22 traffic? Many firewalls (especially in public places) will block all traffic through this and other sensitive ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ssh: Connect to host bitbucket.org port:22 connection time out

This has nothing to do with your ssh key. Your attempts to connect to bitbucket are being blocked, most likely by something within your network.

You could start by checking whether you're running a firewall on your PC that might be blocking outgoing connections to port 22. Also check with your network administrators or your ISP whether outgoing traffic to port 22 is blocked.

Worst case, contact bitbucket for assistance. [They used to support ssh through port 443](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2010/12/17/port-22-blocked-cant-use-ssh-no-problem/), but apparently dropped that feature.

Comment: altssh:443 is still supported: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html